# Google Earth Engine reproject method not giving desired resolution

Tags: google-earth-engine, resolution

I want to have raster with 30 m resolution. Using EE's [reproject](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/apidocs/ee-image-reproject) method:

```
lulc.reproject(crs='EPSG:4326', scale=30) (OR)
lulc.resample('bilinear').reproject(crs='EPSG:4326', scale=30)
```

Is giving raster with pixel size 0.02 but a 30m resolution raster has pixel size of 0.002 (Checked in QGIS)

I also used the following reference apart from the docs to know how to get higher resolution in Earth Engine: [Resampling image or imagecollection to higher resolution in Google Earth Engine Python API](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/316596/resampling-image-or-imagecollection-to-higher-resolution-in-google-earth-engine)

Edit: By changing the value of scale to 3 instead of 30, I got the pixel size in QGIS to 0.002 but I would like to know the difference between the scale in EE and the 30m resolution

Comment: What you're seeing is almost certainly that QGIS is showing scale in something like degrees or minutes, while Earth Engine is using meters.

But it's hard to tell how that's playing out without knowing how you are getting the data from Earth Engine to QGIS.  What parameters are you using for the download?

Answer (score 0):

Earth Engine and QGIS resolution are different. Also the parameter `scale` in `reproject(crs='EPSG:4326', scale=30)` does not give 30m resolution output.

If I change value of scale to `scale=3`, then I'm getting a 30m resolution output. 30m resolution on QGIS is equivalent to pixel size of 0.0002

This is what I observed.

There is a doc on Earth Engine about the scale they are using https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/guides/scale (But I couldn't comprehend)