# Resampling Sentinel-2 ImageCollection on GEE having the bands with the same spatial resolution

Tags: javascript, google-earth-engine, remote-sensing, sentinel-2, resampling

I'm a beginner at Google Earth Engine.
I've seen on previous topics that resampling can be made on single images, like in this topic on [downscaling](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/263986/downscaling-raster-images-in-google-earth-engine) raster images. I have an ImageCollection of Sentinel-2 data and would like to resample at least the bands with 20 m spatial resolution to a 10 m. This is the part of the code working on data collection.

```
var area = ee.Geometry.Polygon([[8.647458, 44.659079],[8.588429, 44.658882],[8.587969, 44.723788],[8.647064, 44.723985]]);

/**FUNCTION to MASK CLOUDS using the Sentinel-2 QA band
@param {ee.Image} image Sentinel-2 image
@return {ee.Image} cloud masked Sentinel-2 image**/
function maskS2clouds(image) { 
    var qa = image.select('QA60');
    //Bits 10 and 11 are clouds and cirrus, respectively
    var cloudBitMask = 1 << 10;
    var cirrusBitMask = 1 << 11; 
    //Both flags should be set to zero, indicating clear conditions
    var mask = qa.bitwiseAnd(cloudBitMask).eq(0).and(qa.bitwiseAnd(cirrusBitMask).eq(0));
    //Return masked and scaled data, without the QA bands
    return image.updateMask(mask).divide(10000).select("B.*").copyProperties(image, ["system:time_start"]);
}

//define collection parameters 
var start = '2017-11-01';
var end = '2018-10-31';
var cld_max = 20;   //max % cloud cover allowed in image collection; for data until now used: 20
    
//collect S2 data
var s2 = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2_SR')
              .filterBounds(aoi)
              .filterDate(start,end)
              // Pre-filter to get less cloudy granules
              .filter(ee.Filter.lt('CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE',cld_max))
              .map(maskS2clouds);
```

But, when it comes to the resampling procedure, doesn't seem to work

```
var b8 = s2.select('B8'); // 10-m resolution
var b8a = s2.select('B8A'); // 20-m resolution

// Get information about the S2 projection at different resolutions
var s2_10m = ee.Image(s2.first().select('B8')); 
var proj = s2_10m.projection(); 
print('S2 projection (10m-res):', proj);

var s2_20m = ee.Image(s2.first().select('B8A')); 
var proj = s2_20m.projection(); 
print('S2 projection (20m-res):', proj);

var transform = [10, proj.transform[1], proj.transform[2], proj.transform[3], -10, proj.transform[5]]; 
print('new CRS transform:', transform);

// Display resampled image collection
var b8a_res = b8a.first().resample('bilinear').reproject({crs: proj.crs, crsTransform: transform});
Map.addLayer(b8a_res, {'min': 0, 'max': 0.5}, 'nNIR_resampled');
```

And reports the

> nNIR_resampled: Layer error: Can't encode object: function standin(_0) {
> return newF.apply(this, arguments);
> }

Is there a better way to resample the image collection 'B8A' (narrow NIR) to a 10-m spatial resolution (just like NIR and RGB bands)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a similar problem and I solved it with a function to be applied to the image collection. I adapted it to your code, I hope it works for you too.

```
var area = ee.Geometry.Polygon([[8.647458, 44.659079],[8.588429, 44.658882],[8.587969, 44.723788],[8.647064, 44.723985]]);

/**FUNCTION to MASK CLOUDS using the Sentinel-2 QA band
@param {ee.Image} image Sentinel-2 image
@return {ee.Image} cloud masked Sentinel-2 image**/
function maskS2clouds(image) { 
    var qa = image.select('QA60');
    //Bits 10 and 11 are clouds and cirrus, respectively
    var cloudBitMask = 1 << 10;
    var cirrusBitMask = 1 << 11; 
    //Both flags should be set to zero, indicating clear conditions
    var mask = qa.bitwiseAnd(cloudBitMask).eq(0).and(qa.bitwiseAnd(cirrusBitMask).eq(0));
    //Return masked and scaled data, without the QA bands
    return image.updateMask(mask).divide(10000).select("B.*").copyProperties(image, ["system:time_start"]);
}

//define collection parameters 
var start = '2017-11-01';
var end = '2018-10-31';
var cld_max = 20;   //max % cloud cover allowed in image collection; for data until now used: 20
    
var s2 = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2_SR')
    .filterBounds(area)
    .filterDate(start,end)
    // Pre-filter to get less cloudy granules
    .filter(ee.Filter.lt('CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE',cld_max))
    .map(maskS2clouds);
    
var b8 = s2.select('B8'); // 10-m resolution
var b8a = s2.select('B8A'); // 20-m resolution
    
//resampling procedure option

var proj_10m = b8.first()//Access to the first image of the colection 
              .projection();//this is an object with all the information about the projection needed for a 10m resolution

function resample(image) { 
    var b8a = image.select('B8A');
    var b8a_res = b8a.resample('bilinear').reproject(proj_10m);
    return b8a_res;
}


var b8a_res =b8a.map(resample)

//print ("projection of the first image from collection b8a (20m) "+b8a.first().projection())
//print ("projection of the first image from collection b8a_res (10m) "+b8a_res.first().projection())



var  paletaImagenes = {"bands":"B8A","min":-1,"max":1,"palette":["blue","white","green"]}


Map.addLayer(b8a,paletaImagenes,'b8a_20m');
Map.addLayer(b8a_res,paletaImagenes,'b8a_10m');
```